# Win10/Win11 can't run any program soon after login

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, windows-11

**Intro**: I'm a repair tech, and I have encountered a very weird problem with two Windows laptops in under a week, something I have never experienced before. One with Windows 10, another with Windows 11, with extremely similar suspicious symptoms.

I will provide more details about Windows 10 laptop, since I had more time to spend with it. Originally, when Windows 11 laptop came in with these symptoms, I couldn't figure it out, and the customer decided not to do anything about it, so I returned the device as it was. "Windows being Windows" - I thought to myself. But after a Windows 10 laptop with very similar behavior came in within a couple of days, this started to seem way too suspicious.

**Symptoms**: can't run any program on the computer ~15 seconds after logging in (can run immediately after login). It boots seemingly fine, I log in, then within 15 seconds after I see the desktop, I can open any program. After that, I can't launch any program at all, including Windows stuff. I can still open start menu, I can navigate folders with explorer (Win+E works), but I can't launch literally anything else. Can't open task manager, can't open control panel, can't open cmd, can't open settings.

**Examples include**:

- Ctrl+Alt+Del (no reaction)
- Ctrl+Shift+Esc (no reaction)
- Win key opens start menu, if I type cmd, it finds cmd, but clicking on it or pressing enter does nothing
- No programs from the desktop or taskbar start
- Win+R (opens always ok), I type "cmd", Enter (nothing happens)
- Firefox (nothing happens)
- Pressing shutdown in start menu (nothing happens)

Notice: all of it works completely correctly until ~15 seconds after getting to desktop. Launching anything as administrator changes nothing.

- At the same time, Win+E (open explorer - folders) works always

Yes, Win+E works, Ctrl+Alt+Del doesn't work. I'm confused.

**What I did to diagnose/solve the issue**:
Upon getting to desktop, I quickly opened task manager (while I still could), it launched okay and it keeps working OK even when things stop launching (but I can't open another task manager anymore). Nothing out of the ordinary. CPU clock seems ok for an idling machine (~1.3-1.4 GHz, not the newest CPU, nothing suspicious, 1%-5% CPU usage, mostly 1%-2%). When I try to launch something like Firefox, CPU usage never goes above 5%, as if I never tried to launch anything.

I also ran `sfc /scannow` (quickly did cmd after boot). It completed. Said it found and corrected some errors (there was no description of any errors, just said that it did something). I rebooted afterwards only to find no difference.

This Huawei laptop has some kind of hardware diagnostic tool built-in. As expected, it found nothing out of the ordinary.

**Other notable details about Windows 10 laptop**:

- Windows partition of SSD has only 3GB of free space
- The laptop has 8GB of RAM, but only 6.9GB are marked as usable. No idea if it's bad, but 1.1GB lost seems a little too much
- Windows build: Windows 10 22H2, build 19045.3693
- Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19053.1000.0 (whatever that is)

For diagnostics, I booted the laptop from live Windows 10 USB stick. Everything launches, everything works. Live USB Windows 10 features:

- Windows 10 build is 19045.2965
- Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19041.1000.0

Given two devices - a Windows 11 laptop and a Windows 10 laptop - came in almost at the same time with pretty much identical problems, Windows Update is my primary suspect at this point, but I have no evidence to back it up, and even less idea about what to do with it. I also failed to turn up anything on the internet that would be relevant to this situation. No mentions of similar issues, no connections to Windows Update of any sort, recently or not.

**Question/request**: In other words, I have no idea what the problem is and what to do about it. I was hoping if anyone could point me in the right direction.

**Addition 1**: out of curiosity I decided to restart the Explorer process, just to see what would happen. Explorer closed and...never restarted. And Win+E does nothing. Until the next reboot, that is.

**Update 1**: as proposed in the comments, I did a safe boot, and the issue goes away in safe boot. The argument about malicious process injecting itself into the login process sounds reasonable given the circumstances. I booted from my Live USB Windows 10, and currently running a full scan using Windows Defender, as well as Dr. Web CureIT. It's been running for a couple of hours now, so far 0 threats found. Will report back once the scans complete.

**Update 2**: Dr.Web CureIT and Windows Defender both found exactly zero threats on the user drive.

**Update 3**: as proposed, in safe mode (where the problem doesn't happen), I did Win+R, `shell:common startup`. It opened an empty startup folder. Next, I have disabled all Autostart programs in the Task Manager, almost all of which were from Microsoft. When I booted normally (not safe boot), Ctrl+Shift+Esc worked for 15 seconds and stopped. Nothing changed. The problem remains.

Comment: Can you boot in safe mode? What happens there?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously as malware that that gets started during the login process and messes with the loading mechanism of executables. It isn't immediately active so you have still a small window after login during which is isn't active yet.
Try booting in safe mode and/or login in with a different user-account. Possibly it won't load in that case. And virusscan the system while booted from clean media.

Comment: The other thing that users might have done is install older or non-compliant software. Windows Repair Install often needed.

Comment: Check the Event Viewer for suspicious messages. Run a deep antivirus scan.

Comment: Did a safe boot (no symptoms present). Booted from Live USB Win10, running a full user drives' scan. Updated the question with details.

Comment: In safe mode, open task manager and let us know what is listed in the startup programs list. Try disabling all of them and re-test in normal mode. Then re-enable one at a time until the problem comes back. Also, while in safe mode go to this in the run menu: `shell:common startup`. You want to check that there aren't any shortcuts to strange execs in there. If there is, delete them.

Comment: Did that, details in the post. Unfortunately, didn't help. I'm leaning towards backing up user data (hopefully, after antivirus scans I wanna think it's clean) and doing clean Windows install at this point for purely economic reasons, but if we find a less invasive solution, that would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general consesus in the comments (and I agree with it) is that some malware injected itself into the login procedure, most likely modified some system files. Unfortunately, no antivirus scans found anything malicious (zero threats found). The most reasonable solution at this point was to save user's files (which were already scanned by antivirus software), format the drive and do a clean install of Windows, eliminating chances of the issue to reappear.

Upon clean install, the system works stable, as expected.

**UPDATE :** several users are linking the issue to a **recent faulty Avira update**. Info can be found on the **Avira subreddit** r/Avira and **various technews website**, some of them who reached out to the antivirus company which confirmed the issue.